# How to score links in a network represented as graph?

Tags: network, networking, bandwidth, packet-loss, throughput

I am working on an academic research about networks. I have proposed my model a a graph that nodes are users with commodity hardware connected to each other via internet as graph links. I know this is a weighted graph. My question is:
*How can I score links based on different features such as throughput or distance between users?*
I have read several papers. One of them had a figure that shows the relationship between throughput and distance with packet loss:
[image]
I can't understand why packet loss increases when throughput increases. Isn't throughput a positive aspect?

**Edit:** Is there any mathematics equation for the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I score links based on different features such as throughput or distance between users?

A common gauge is the *bandwidth-distance product* - since high bandwidth and long distance are somewhat equally hard to achieve and often traded off against each other, their product is a fairly good measure for the grade of achievement.

> I can't understand why packet loss increases when throughput increases. Isn't throughput a positive aspect?

The graph shows the relation of packet loss to distance for some throughput scenarios. It does not show a direct relation of packet loss to throughput.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As for certain distance, if we increase throughput, packet loss rate will increase. Doesn't it mean a direct relation?

Comment: No. It all depends on the situation at hand. For wired networks, packet loss on non-congested links is zero (< 10^-12), even for dozens of km.